# RobotFramework: Append to string not returning in string form

Tags: robotframework

Below code i am using to append a string to another string, but it gives these **u"**   characters in it. How do i stop it from doing this. I want to assign the variable query string so that i can use it later.

```
KEYWORD BuiltIn . Set Variable ${query_string}, ${query_string} AND
Documentation:  
Returns the given values which can then be assigned to a variables.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170419 09:38:38.175 / 20170419 09:38:38.176 / 00:00:00.001
09:38:38.175    TRACE   Arguments: [ "Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01'" | "Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01' AND" ]  
09:38:38.175    TRACE   Return: ["Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01'", "Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01' AND"]    
09:38:38.144    TRACE   Arguments: [ '3 > 1' | 'Set Variable' | '${query_string}' | '${query_string} AND' | 'ELSE' | 'Set Variable' | '${query_string}' | '${query_string}' ]   
09:38:38.176    TRACE   Return: ["Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01'", "Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01' AND"]    
09:38:38.176    INFO    ${query_string} = [u"Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01'", u"Select * from patients where randomisation_date = '2017-01-01' AND"]
```

Comment: What's your RF version? What's your python version? Read first `Note` here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rules-for-parsing-the-data

Comment: The u stands for Unicode. So can you highlight the error you're getting?